# How to avoid OutOfMemoryErrors when processing big analysis reports?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

Running SonarQube 5.6.6 from Jenkins on CentOS 7.3, I got the following error:

> 2017.09.01 19:05:16 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AV485bp0qXlQ-QPWWE9A
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   2017.09.01 19:05:17 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=PP::Symphony3M | type=REPORT | id=AV485bp0qXlQ-QPWWE9A | time=74089ms

`sonar.ce.javaOpts` is set like below:

> sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx60g -Xms1g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

How much heap space should I give to SonarQube, when analyzing a one million LOC project? Or is there another way of avoiding Java heap space issues?

Comment: Maybe you should split your project in logical parts.

Comment: How can the analysis results be linked then?

Answer (score 0):

The max heap you can allocate depends on the free Ram on your server. free command can help identify the stats. Based on free Ram you can set your Xmx values.

BTW, make sure the code compiles on a server. If you are able to compile and not scan then only the increasing the heap will help.

Comment: The project can be built on the server with 64GB of memory.